# Conditional probability -conditioning on a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) $ be a probability space, $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $X$ a random variable. What does it mean $$ \mathbb{P} (A | X) $$ when $X$ is not discrete?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know conditional expectations (i.e. something of the form $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathcal{F})$ where $Y$ is a random variable and $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra)?

Comment: Yes, I know conditional expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,

$$\mathbb{P}(A \mid X) := \mathbb{E}(1_A \mid \sigma(X))$$

where $\sigma(X)$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$, i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that $X$ is measurable.

Comment: If we have something like $\mathbb{P} (X \in A | \mathcal{F_s})$, then $$ \mathbb{P} (X \in A | \mathcal{F_s}) = E (1_{\{X \in A\}} | \mathcal{F_s}) $$?

Comment: @rodie Yes, exactly.